# Doctrine native query(createNativeQuery) select query for 1 million rows high memory usage

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm

I am trying to select a million rows with Doctrine but am having some problems.

First I've tried doing it using the ORM query, but then I found out the native query is faster.(I don't need the ORM mapping for this).

I am already using an array hydrator(creating objects would be pointless since I need to only read the data).

I also heard about the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, but I get an error if I turn it off, since I am working with multiple result sets(cursors) at the same time.

So the memory usage is damn high.
Around 100 MB ram just for one integer column on about 1.3 Mil rows.

Example part of my code(using the non-custom HYDRATE_ARRAY):

```
function getResult() { 
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$q = $this->getEntityManager()->
createNativeQuery("select {$this->getTableIdColName()} 
from {$this->getTableName()}", $rsm);
return $q->iterate(null, \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

Upon calling said function, even if I don't iterate it at all - the memory is taken.
I've also made a custom hydrator which pretty much does the same as the default one but uses less memory(since it doesn't map column names). But the result ain't good either way.

Am I missing something or is it normal for a query to take 100 MB of ram without even using the result?

Comment: A million is quite a few rows.  Not something that php is normally used to process. Try using Doctrine DBAL, http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html. or maybe even straight PDO.  But even if you get the results trying to do anything with it in the context of php is going to be challenging.

Comment: Well, I can easily use 10 mil rows on an iterator basis. Basically a huge foreach, which hydrates a row, uses it, frees the memory and so on.

Perhaps I will try doing multiple selects instead. But what's bothering me is the fact that the mere call $q->iterate(null, \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY); takes the memory. And I can't free it in any way.(And am not too sure if Php 5.6's GC is good enough) to do it without explicit unset/free.

Through I agree with you - If I don't get an answer on this one - I am probably just gonna go pure PDO for that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Query buffering, for anyone interested:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

By default, it's enabled, hence the whole results are being kept in memory.

Basically this fixes the problem, but it imposes some limitations:

1. Requires you to consume/close all results before making new queries to the database(doctrine has no internal way of closing them by the way)

`$em->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection()->setAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);`